# Iterating through a collection without order

Tags: c#, collections, foreach

I'm stuck on a C# problem and I hope you can help me.

I'm trying to find a way to reach all elements of a collection without order, ie. at the same time.

```
 //We are in the Planification Class

public void AddProduct(ProductFinal product, DateTime date, double quantity)
    {
        if (planificationLines== null)
        {
            planificationLines= new List<planificationLine>();
        }
        PlanificationLine planificationLine= new PlanificationLigne(this, product, date, quantity);
        planificationLines.Add(planificationLine);
        ProcessPlanification(planificationLine);
    }

    public void ProcessPlanification(PlanificationLine planificationLine)
    {


        //Load all recipes
        List<Recipes> listeFT = LoadAllRecipes().ToList();


        //Change the Quantity to produce of the FinalProduct ordered in planificationLine
        planificationLine.Product.QuantityToProduce+= planificationLine.QuantityToProduce;

//Compute QuantityToProduce for others 
foreach (Recipe FT in listeFT)
        { 
            foreach (RecipeLine item in FT.Ingredients)
            {
                item.Product.QuantityToProduce += FT.ResultProduct.Quantity* item.Proportion;
            }
        }
```

But here, let's guess I have 2 recipes, with one using the other:
for example: 
FinishedChicken (95% of Salted Chicken, 5% secret ingredient)
SaltedChicken (95% of chicken, 5% salt).
Let's say I plan 10 kilos of FinishedChicken:
If in the foreach statement, SaltedChicken comes first, it will fix the  QuantitytoProduce of chicken to 0 when it is supposed to be 10*0.95*0.95.

I hope I've been clear, if not, just ask.
Do you have any idea?
Thx

Comment: So your issue is with the last foreach?

Comment: its difficult to understand all these abstractions without seeing actual class. I guess what you need is decorator pattern.

Comment: @singsuyash Classes are pretty straightforward, Planification & PlanificationLine/ Recipe & RecipeLine/ Products with quantity and Time. Would it be helpful to write them down?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to iterate over a collection *without* order, you want to iterate over a collection in such an order that you never encounter a `Recipe` unless all of its ingredients have already been encountered.

Working out such an order would be very complicated, and I think it's best to avoid this approach.

I won't try to write C# code as I'm not very familiar with the language, but I think you need two classes, `PrimitiveIngredient` and `Recipe`. You would need a method that takes a `Recipe` and produces a list of `PrimitiveIngredients` with their amount. You would write this by iterating over the `Recipe`'s items and recursively calling the method if an `item` is itself a `Recipe` (rather than a `PrimitiveIngredient`).

Comment: I'm giving it a try. I see your point there, just need some time to try it to make the link with the planification. thx for the answer, I'll come back to tell if it worked

Comment: It works fine, thank you very much for the recursive idea! I'm posting the final code as an answer